# What is best example for Navigation Drawer in Material Design in low API

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, material-design

I trying find more info how create best Navigation Drawer panel with Material Desing's guidelines.

Google recommended page [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). This example based on Support Library v4.

Also link about v7 [AppCompat v21 — Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices!](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). This work fine only on Android API 21+. I can't use this Material Desing in lower OS's vesion, because If I set `target=android-20` (or less) in `project.properties` I get errors in Eclipse (several hundred):

```
C:\<workspace>\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'
....
:( several hundred error in 'values-v21' directory
....
```

I use features of low Android API, that was deprecated or undefined in Android API 21+. But I need support Material Design in low API (14+).

Please give examples of creating Navigation Drawer on low Android API 14+.

Comment: You're confusing minSdkVersion with targetSdkVersion. The first one defines the minimum required Android version that has to be present on a device. The second one is just the version you're using for development. You should set targetSdkVersion to as high as possible and minSdkVersion to the version you would like to support.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a dependency :

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2" (or use newer)
```

Layout :

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbardrawer"
    />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/mytoolbardrawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_drawer"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="171dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_drawer"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_4"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_drawer"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Drawer Activity :

```
        import android.content.res.Configuration;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.text.Html;
        import android.text.SpannableString;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


        public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            Toolbar t;
            private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            private ListView mDrawerList;
            private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
            private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

            private CharSequence mDrawerTitle,mTitle;

            private String[] navMenuItems;
            private SpannableString[] navmenuItems;
            private ArrayAdapter<SpannableString> adapter;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
                t=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.mytoolbardrawer);
                setSupportActionBar(t);

                initStuffs();

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                   new SliderMenuClickListener().displayView(0);
                }
            }

            private void initStuffs() {
                mTitle=mDrawerTitle=getTitle();
                navMenuItems=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
                mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                mDrawerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
                mRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_drawer);

                navmenuItems=new SpannableString[navMenuItems.length];
                for(int i=0;i<navMenuItems.length;i++) {
                    navmenuItems[i] = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>" + navMenuItems[i] + "</font>"));
                }
                adapter=new ArrayAdapter<SpannableString>(DrawerActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,navmenuItems);
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

                mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(DrawerActivity.this,mDrawerLayout,t,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View view){
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                };
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
                mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SliderMenuClickListener());
            }


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                boolean drawerOpen=mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mRelativeLayout);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
                mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }

            @Override
            public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
                super.setTitle(title);
                mTitle=title;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                    return true;
                }
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            private class SliderMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    displayView(position);
                }

                private void displayView(int position) {
                    Fragment fragment=null;
                    switch (position){
                        case 0:
                                fragment=new HomeFragment();
                                break;
                        case 1:
                            fragment=new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            fragment=new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            fragment=new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        default:break;
                    }
                    if(fragment!=null){
                        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
                        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position,true);
                        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                        setTitle(navMenuItems[position]);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mRelativeLayout);
                    }else{
                        Log.e("DrawerActivity","Error creating fragment");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```